# MySQL 1064 syntax error when using statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1064

I am running a server that receives queries and sends them to the Database using Statements.

```
try{
    connection = dbConnection.getDbConnection();
    if(connection != null) {
         System.out.println("DA2");

        Statement mySt = connection.createStatement();
        if(mySt != null) {
           ResultSet myRs = mySt.executeQuery(query);
           System.out.println("DA3");

           while(myRs.next()){
               //getting data and printing it
           }
        }

}
```

It prints DA2 so the connection is created succefully.
The query is send by the client in the following way

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
String query = "USE db_name; SELECT * FROM `tb_name`;";
out.writeUTF(query);
```

I changed the database name with db_name and the table name with tb_name(I am sure I wrote them correctly in my code).

The server receives them this way

```
Socket client = socket.accept();
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
String query = input.readUTF();
```

When the server is running and the client sends the query an exception is thrown with the following message(I handled the exceptions to show me this).

> SQLState: 42000
>   Error Code: 1064
>   Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM `tb_name`' at line 1

The same query runs correctly on a MySQL database.

How can I solve this? Is the database sending back the error and so throwing an exception or is it just the code?

**SOLVED: I forgot to specify the database name in the connection.**

Comment: Please fix your tags. SQL Server or mySQL

Comment: You should never use `USE <database-name>` when using a JDBC driver. Either connect to the right database or use `setCatalog` to switch. See also the [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#idm140128770429744).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use (single SQL statement with qualified name):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM db_name.`tb_name`";
```

Comment: It also works this way(without setting the database name). Thank you! I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Connection dbConnect() {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException " + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException " + e);
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Hope you have created dbConnect in similar fashion.
Here We heve included the database name in get connection method
So explicitly no need to use database name for each time until  you are accessing another database.

so your query should be

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_name`";
```